# Kivy Textinput Wrap

Tags: python, kivy

How do I configure a Kivy text input box such that it wraps the text I paste into it? For example, let's say I have a string that is 1,000 letters long and I paste it into a text input box which has `multiline` enabled. Instead of wrapping to the next line, the pasted text is displayed as one line which runs beyond the width of the window. Very unexpected behavior.

A string pasted into TextInput with id `seq_input_box`

```
UUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUUUUCUUAUUU
```

.kv file:

```
MinRoot:

<MinRoot>:
    MyForm

<MyForm>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    seq_input: seq_input_box
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            text: "Go!"
            on_press: root.calc_seq()
    TextInput:
        id: seq_input_box
        focus: True
```

Result:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code, a [mcve]? It works here.

Comment: It looks like this is a limitation of the word wrapping algorithm, in `TextInput._split_smart`. The case of a word longer than the widget width is pathological and not currently handled. Either you'll have to subclass `TextInput` and modify `_split_smart` or you introduce some kind of logical delimiter into your string (any of these characters: `u' ,\'".;:\n\r\t'`), which might also aid readability.

Comment: By the way, if anyone is feeling smart enough to modify `_split_smart` to accommodate my use case, you'll be my hero for the week. Ideally, it would accept an argument representing how many letters each line can have, default 50. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@zeeMonkeez, thank you for looking into the root cause of this problem. Here is the solution I ended up using:

**.py file:**

```
class MyTextBox(TextInput):

    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):

        line_length = 50

        # Remove all whitespace in string.
        seq = ''.join(substring.split())

        # For every line_length characters, insert a newline character.
        if len(seq) > line_length:

            # Splits seq by every Nth character and creates a list.
            # Example: [abc,def,ghi]
            # Then join the list items together using a newline character
            # as the separator.
            seq = '\n'.join([seq[i:i+line_length] for i in range(0, len(seq), line_length)])

        return super(MyTextBox, self).insert_text(seq, from_undo=from_undo)
```

More info about `insert_text` is available [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#filtering).